# Table does not exist in engine phpmyadmin error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a serious problem. I want to restore some MySQL database table files in PHPMyAdmin. The problem I have is that I was using Windows 10 as an operating system which crushed.

I then removed the hard drive and made it a secondary drive. I was then able to access the MySQL folder from the xammp folder. I installed xammp on the new hard drive then copied and pasted the MySQL folder to the to the new xampp instance. Now when I try to access the tables from MySQL in PHPMyAdmin, it tells me the table does not exist in the engine.

Comment: If you know the pattern of those files and  if you have knowledge on database , is it not feasible to create on your own?

Comment: @karanarora, as in create my own data?

Comment: Yes, if you know the table names , you can export the data either in csv or .sql through workbench client tool.